# Display data on selection

Tags: javascript, html

I started learning DOM, i just wanted to test something, I've created drop down list using  i wanted to display data on according with the selection. I don't know whether i wrote it correct or not.

Thank you in advance for help.

```js
var show = document.getElementById("show");
var select = document.getElementById("select");
if(select == "Boots"){
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("You selected Boots");
  show.appendChild(newContent);
}
else if(select == "Socks"){
  var newContent2 = document.createTextNode("You selected Socks");
  show.appendChild(newContent2);
}
else{
  var newContent2 = document.createTextNode("You selected Tie");
  show.appendChild(newContent2);
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <p class="lead">Please Choose one in the following</p>
 <form>
<select class="custom-select" id="select">
  <option class="active">Choose one...</option>
<option>Boots</option>
<option>Socks</option>
<option>tie</option>
</select>
  </form><br>
<p id="show" class="lead">

</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem we need to solve for you?

Comment: If i select boots it should display "you choose Boots". But it constantly showing you choose tie irrespective of selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to wrap your code inside the `onchange` event handler so your code runs every time the selection changes. Then there is no need to keep appending child nodes every time the selection changes, simply set the `innerHTML` of your `show` element. Also unless you consider `"tie"` to be the default value you may want to check for that:

Then you need to get the value of the selected item correctly. One way is to do `select.options[select.selectedIndex].text` which will get the text value of the selected `option` element.

```js
var show = document.getElementById("show");
var select = document.getElementById("select");

select.onchange = function(){
  value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  if(value == "Boots"){
    show.innerHTML = "You selected Boots";
  }
  else if(value == "Socks"){
    show.innerHTML = "You selected Socks";
  }
  else if(value == "tie"){
    show.innerHTML = "You selected Tie";
  }
  else {
    show.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <p class="lead">Please Choose one in the following</p>
 <form>
<select class="custom-select" id="select">
  <option class="active">Choose one...</option>
<option>Boots</option>
<option>Socks</option>
<option>tie</option>
</select>
  </form><br>
<p id="show" class="lead">

</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you forr the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to the dropdown and trigger a function every time the selected value changes. This function can be made to replace the text displayed. Try the code below.

```js
var show = document.getElementById("show");
var select = document.getElementById("select");

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  show.innerHTML = "You selected " + this.value;
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="lead">Please Choose one in the following</p>
    <form>
      <select class="custom-select" id="select">
  <option class="active">Choose one...</option>
<option value="Boots">Boots</option>
<option value="Socks">Socks</option>
<option value="tie">tie</option>
</select>
    </form><br>
    <p id="show" class="lead">

    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have added `value` attributes to the `<option>` tag so that values can be easily retrieved in the code. You don't need the `if..else if` statements in your code for this case.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```js
function change(){
    var show = document.getElementById("show");
    var select = event.target.value;
    var newContent = "You selected "+ select;
    show.innerHTML = newContent;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <p class="lead">Please Choose one in the following</p>
 <form>
<select class="custom-select" id="select" onchange="change()">
  <option class="active">Choose one...</option>
<option>Boots</option>
<option>Socks</option>
<option>tie</option>
</select>
  </form><br>
<p id="show" class="lead">

</p>
  </div>
</body>
```